# Visa-free countries with a UK Refugee travel document

Tags: visas, customs-and-immigration, refugees, kosovo

I have a UK Refugee Travel Document (RTD).

I am planning to visit Kosovo soon. But when I check my visa requirement I see different information in different places and it is confusing.

With my UK Refugee Travel Document (and permission to stay), do I need a visa to go to Kosovo?

In addition, sharing an up-to-date general information about the countries where we can go visa-free with RTD will make this subject clear for many people.

Comment: Kosovo is an oddly particular place to visit.  Are you a refugee *from the Balkans conflicts*?  If so there's stuff we need to talk about.

Answer (score 3):

I do not think that the UK publishes such a list. The relevant web page https://www.gov.uk/apply-home-office-travel-document/refugee-travel-document states:

> Before you travel
>
> Check which documents you’ll need before you book your travel.
>
> Ask the authorities of the country you’re visiting or travelling through if:
>
> - the country accepts refugee travel documents
> - you need a visa to enter the country

Post-Brexit, any visa-free travel agreements that may have existed with individual EU countries for refugees who hold a Convention travel document issued by the UK are no longer valid.

As well as checking the entry requirements directly with the country(ies) you’re interested in on their respective websites, you can find advice here https://www.gov.uk/foreign-travel-advice and on the IATA website https://www.iatatravelcentre.com/

Comment: Actually the convention providing for visa free travel for refugees was separate from the EU, and the UK withdrew from it several years before leaving the EU.