# Do i need a visa to go to Portugal i have 1951 UN convention travel document

Tags: customs-and-immigration, visa-free-entry, portugal, refugees, uk-residents

I have 1951 UN travel document issued in United Kingdom, Do i need a visa to go to Portugal for 4 days?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Visa-free countries with a UK Refugee travel document](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/180799/visa-free-countries-with-a-uk-refugee-travel-document)

Comment: @Traveller the question is similar, but there doesn't really seem to be an answer there

Answer (score 2):

I haven’t been able to find an official source, however according to https://immigrationandmigration.com/countries-that-allow-visa-free-travel-with-refugee-travel-documents/ Portugal **does not** allow visa-free entry to visitors with the Refugee Travel Document (blue) issued by the UK under the 1951 UN Convention.

You can check on the IATA site by entering your personal details and your intended travel itinerary https://www.iatatravelcentre.com/